# R ggplot2: How to get a function in with the text of the axis title?

Tags: r, function, ggplot2, axis-labels

I would like my plot axis title to include among the text a function that performs a calculation on some data.

For example here are some data

```
a<-data.frame(time="1000",x=rnorm(10,12,3))
b<-data.frame(time="2000",x=rnorm(50,13,4))
c<-data.frame(time="3500",x=rnorm(50,12,4))
d<-data.frame(time="5000",x=rnorm(7,14,5))
e<-data.frame(time="7000",x=rnorm(20,10,3))
f<-data.frame(time="7500",x=rnorm(15,11,3))
g<-data.frame(time="9000",x=rnorm(15,10,5))
h<-data.frame(time="9500",x=rnorm(35,30,2))
i<-data.frame(time="10000",x=rnorm(30,28,4))
a2i<-rbind(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i) 

library(ggplot2)
a2i$time<-as.numeric(levels(a2i$time))[a2i$time] 
ggplot(a2i,aes(time,x))+stat_smooth()+geom_point()+
# now let's try to put on a label with a function
# mixed in with the text
#
xlab("Time (total number of observations = paste(length(a2i$x))))")
#
# but that's no good, the function is not executed, just printed
# How can I get a function to work in the axis title?
```

[image]

I'd like to keep "time" in the title as a constant, but have the function return different results as the data change. And get the parentheses in there as well.

I've had a go with paste() and expression(), but I'm not having much luck. Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should first build a string that contains the test you want,
with `paste` or `sprintf`, and then feed it to `xlab`.
In particular, `paste` should not be inside the string.

```
xlab( paste( 
  "Time (total number of observations = ", 
  length(a2i$x), 
  ")", 
  sep="" 
) )

# Equivalently
xlab( sprintf( 
  "Time (total number of observations = %s)", 
  length(a2i$x) 
) )
```

Comment: That has done the job perfectly. Thanks very much for your quick answer! Getting `paste` in the front of the whole string was something I hadn't tried.